# How to change path with python script using os module

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, python-os

I'm trying to change the directory of my terminal from a Python script. The program execute successfully but the directory in my terminal doesn't change. Here is the program.

```
os

path = "/home/najeeb/Desktop/project/scan"

r = os.getcwd()
print "\n Current working directery is %s \n" % r

os.chdir(path)
retval = os.getcwd()

print "Directery changes successfull %s \n" % retval
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Each program on the system has its own Current-Working-Directory and child processes cannot change their parent's working directory.  In your example, the command-line-shell is one program that invokes `python` in order to execute your script.  Your script's scope is limited to that `python` program.

Answer (score 0):

Python can't change what directory your terminal is running in. It can only change the path inside of the script.

Comment: so how to change directory in terminal using python script?

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary As I said in my answer. You can't.

Comment: but in python shall. python script can change directory normaly

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary Yes, you can change what directory the Python script runs in with Python. You cannot change the directory of the parent process (the terminal).

Comment: are you say it not possible to change directory using python script?

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary Yes.